# Event emitter in angular 2 not catch up

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 beta 6.

My custom event is not catched up

```
import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {Output} from "angular2/core";
@Component({
    template: '<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #registrationForm="ngForm" style="color: #676767">
         <button type="submit" >Send Event</button>
   </form>'

})
export class registrationComponent {

    @Output() logged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    onSubmit () {
        console.log(Button clicked);
        this.logged.emit(null); // Emits an event on clicking the button
         }

}
```

I added another component with listening to my event logged.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'message-com',
    template: '<div (logged)="getLoggedIn($event)">Hello<div>'
})
export class MessageComponent {


    getLoggedIn() {

        alert("Event received ");

    }
}
```

I am getting "Button clicked" in my console. But I am expecting "Event received "

Comment: Please add more information. What is the selector of `registrationComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

```
templateUrl: <div (logged)="getLoggedIn($event)">Hello<div>'
```

should be

```
template: '<div (logged)="getLoggedIn($event)">Hello<div>'
```

and a `<div>` doesn't emit the `logged` event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem when linking your two component together (in addition to the problem found by @Günter). You don't use the `registrationComponent` in the `MessageComponent` one. This way you can't catch the event since the `registrationComponent` is actually used in the `MessageComponent` one.

You should refactor your two components this way:

- Add a selector for the `registrationComponent` component:

  ```
  import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
  import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
  import {Output} from "angular2/core";
  @Component({
    selector: 'registration',
    templateUrl: 'views/registration.html'
  })
  export class registrationComponent {
    @Output() logged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    onSubmit () {
      this.logged.emit(null);
    }
  }
  ```
- Set the `registrationComponent` in the `directives` attribute of the `MessageComponent` component and use it thanks to its selector:

  ```
  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
  import {registrationComponent} from '...';

  @Component({
    selector: 'message-com',
    template: `
      <registration (logged)="getLoggedIn($event)">Hello<registration>
    `,
    directives: [ registrationComponent ]
  })
  export class MessageComponent {
    getLoggedIn() {
      alert("Event recieved ");
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: I am loading registraton component and message component in my app component  <registration>Loading ...</registration>
                        <message-com>Loading..</message-com>

Comment: It's not the right way to do :-( Set only your main one `message-com` in your HTML entry file and bootstrap it: `boostrap(MessageComponent);`. Then use the `registrationComponent` component into your `MessageComponent` one. Events are only catched by the parent component so `MessageComponent` needs to be the parent of the `registrationComponent`. That's why you need use `registrationComponent` inside `MessageComponent`...

Comment: I changed the getLoggedIn() {

        alert("Event received ");

    } code to the app.componet.ts file, Is that make sense? Then the registration  is child and it sends event to parent component "app.component".  Is this good ?

Comment: I don't exactly know your use case but it seems good. If you want to exchange event between components that haven't this relationship (parent / child), you could use an `EventEmitter` property within a shared service. See these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719496/toggle-property-in-parent-component-from-child-component-in-angular2-similar-to/35719561#35719561 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436.