# Toggle property in parent Component from Child Component in Angular2 (similar to $emit in AngularJS)

Tags: typescript, angular, eventemitter

I'm currently teaching myself Angular2 and I have a practical problem that would be easy to rectify in AngularJS but currently I'm looking through examples to find a solution with Angular2. Anyway, I have a top level component called `App` and within that component I have a property that applies a css class, here is my HTML that is used as the component template - you can see where I wish to apply the css class using `ngClass`. The `showMenu` value is just a boolean.

```
<div class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Home]">Home</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Mail']">Mail</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Friends']">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Games']">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- below is where I wish to toggle the class -->
<div class="site-wrap" [ngClass]="{'slide-right': showMenu}">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row nav">
            <top-navigation></top-navigation>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid content-gradient">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <contacts-list></contacts-list>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid footer">
        <footer-navigation></footer-navigation>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Component Code for App (not much to see here...)

```
export class App {

    showMenu: boolean = false;
    constructor() {
    }
    // I need to listen for the toggle somehow?
    toggleMenu():void {
        this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
    }

}
```

Now you can see I have a child component with the selector `top-navigation`. This component `TopNavigation` has a method on a button that I wish to toggle the value of `showMenu` in the parent / top-level component. Here's my code so far (just small extracts)

```
export class TopNavigation {

          constructor() {
            // Things happening here
          }

          toggleMenu():void {
            // I want to toggle the parent property by somekind of $emit
          }
    }
```

here is the template HTML (not all) for the Component.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1  hidden-md hidden-lg hamburger-menu">
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="toggleMenu()">&#9776;</button>
</div>
```

In AngularJS I would have an `$scope.$emit` on the `toggleMenu` function and in the parent I would have a `$scope.$on` to listen for the event. I'm currently reading about `EventEmitters` in Angular2 however if anyone has a quick explanation/example I would be most appreciative especially as I think this is a common / practical everyday task for Angular developers.

Comment: If you have a direct parent-child relationship, I prefer Günter's answer.  If you need to toggle the value from multiple components, then go with Theirry's answer (but use an Observable rather than an EventEmitter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could leverage a shared service that define an `EventEmitter` property. Your `App` component will subscribe on it to be notified when the corresponding event is trigger by the `TopNavigation` component.

- Shared service

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class MenuService {
    showMenuEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }
  ```

  Don't forget to define the corresponding provider in the boostrap function to be able to share the same instance of the service for the whole application: `bootstrap(App, [ MenuService ]);
- `App` component

  ```
  @Component({ ... })
  export class App {
    showMenu: boolean = false;
    constructor(menuService: MenuService) {
      menuService.showMenuEvent.subscribe(
        (showMenu) => {
          this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
        }
     );
   }
  ```

  }
- `TopNavigation` component:

  ```
  export class TopNavigation {
    constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {
      // Things happening here
    }

    toggleMenu():void {
      this.showMenu = this.showMenu;
      this.menuService.showMenuEvent.emit(this.showMenu);
    }
  }
  ```

See this question for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)

Comment: That's great and I'm just reading the link however in the emit in the TopNavigation component I assume I don't need to send any data from the .emit() - as I don't maintain the showMenu in that component. However I see how I could pass info should I want to. Also in my MenuService I get the error `Generic type 'EventEmitter<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)` I assume we are missing something there. But your answer was just what I needed - I now understand!

Answer (score 4):

You can use two-way binding.

```
<top-navigation [(toggleMenu)]="showMenu"></top-navigation>
```

maybe one-way would do as well, I don't know your exact requirements

```
<top-navigation (toggleMenuChange)="showMenu=$event"></top-navigation>
```

```
export class TopNavigation {
      @Output() toggleMenuChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

      // for two-way binding
      @Input() toggleMenu:boolean = false;

      constructor() {
        // Things happening here
      }

      toggleMenu():void {
        this.toggleMenu = !this.toggleMenu;
        this.toggleMenu.emit(this.toggleMenu);
      }
}
```